# Entering ascii chars as program input

Tags: terminal, c, input, ascii

If I write a very simple C terminal program that takes an input, how can I enter an ascii character as the input, like for instance the backspace character?

Answer (score 4):

Unless your program modifies the terminal modes, you can prefix special characters (such as backspace) by prefixing them with the *literal next* (`lnext`) character.  That is usually <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

You can see this setting using `stty -a`, e.g.,

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```